# mysql left join not returning values

Tags: mysql, left-join

This seems like a fairly common question on here although I haven't been able to find a solution.

I have three tables,
matchup, matchup_options, matchup_votes

On create, a matchup gets created, "n" matchup_options are created and matchup_votes are empty until a vote is added.

My query is only returning one value even though I have two matchup_options, NEITHER have anything in the matchup_votes table. (These should return 0 until theres an actual entry, which would start counting correctly)

```
SELECT matchup.matchupID, matchup_option.player_id, player.name, player.abr, count(matchup_vote.player_id) votes FROM matchup 
            INNER JOIN matchup_option ON matchup_option.matchupID= matchup.matchupID
            INNER JOIN player ON player.player_id = matchup_option.player_id
            LEFT JOIN matchup_vote ON matchup_vote.player_id = matchup_option.player_id
            GROUP BY matchup_vote.player_id;
```

And the return:

```
matchupID    player_id      name      abr        votes
111          249            Name      SF         0
```

Expected return:

```
matchupID    player_id      name      abr        votes
111          249            Name      SF         0  
111          331            Name2     JS         0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `group by` clause is incorrect. You're grouping by `matchup_vote.player_id`. I can't see your source data, but this implies that only one player has voted.

Your query should look like:

```
SELECT 
  matchup.matchupID
  , matchup_option.player_id
  , player.name
  , player.abr
  , count(matchup_vote.player_id) votes 
FROM 
  matchup 
  INNER JOIN matchup_option 
    ON matchup_option.matchupID = matchup.matchupID
  INNER JOIN player 
    ON player.player_id = matchup_option.player_id
  LEFT JOIN matchup_vote 
    ON matchup_vote.player_id = matchup_option.player_id
GROUP BY 
  matchup.matchupID
  , matchup_option.player_id
  , player.name
  , player.abr
```

Comment: Yep this definitely worked. So essentially, we want to group on the entire dataset not just the one individual field?

Comment: @Nihat: Not the entire dataset, no. Just what's relevant. That usually means everything in the select statement above the aggregate function. Think of how you would break counting groups up in real life. It's the same. If you want to count the cars on a lot, you count them as one group. You can then break them into groups of what kind of car they are, and then even further by color.

Comment: @Nihat: if that solved you problem, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check button :)

Comment: Why are you grouping at all?  You group when you need some aggregation on that group.  For example, when you need an average score for all games by a player, then you might want to group by a player_id.  You should also ask yourself, why this query works the way you want, or if it even does.  We don't have your schema, but I don't know why player_id is part of matchup_option.

Comment: @gview: What, pray tell, do you think the `count()` function is, if not an aggregation function?

Comment: @gview its somewhat of a "poll" system, I'm counting votes based on player_id and matchup_id... matchup_options are a list of players associated with a matchup

Comment: That's what I get for quickly scanning --- you are right.  Question would still be better if the basic schema information was included.

Comment: credit to @Jacobm001 for solving it without all the information then! Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: The main reason I glossed over part of the query is that your question focused on joins.  I understand that you didn't see the issue was related to GROUP BY, but hopefully you now understand it better.  You get one row for every unique combination in the GROUP.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a GROUP BY matchup_vote.player_id;

You will get one row per player_id.